# meaning of 'satyagraha grey'

Tags: meaning

> A: Oh, great. This isn’t just grey. It’s ***satyagraha grey***.
>
> B: Look, it’s pretty black and white to me.

I know 'grey' means 'vague', but what does 'Satyagraha grey' mean?
It seems like it means 'vaguer' in this context.
But I want to know why 'Satyagraha grey' means 'vaguer' exactly.

I already googled it but it didn't help me to understand it perfectly. :-(

Comment: The only result of a search for 'satyagraha grey' is this question. I have no idea what it means - where did you see/hear this? Satyagraha seems to mean a form of non-violent resistance and was coined, according to Wiki, by Ghandi. In the context of 'black and white' grey means rather more than 'vague'. It could mean very complex, hard to work out, not well defined (that would be vague), contradictory, or any other reason that makes a choice difficult.

Comment: Oh, it's a dialogue from a TV show. So it's not a famous thing to say. But thank you for commenting. :-)

Comment: No problem. I can imagine that practicing satyagraha would bring up a number of grey areas - moral choices - so I can see it being used as a description of a particularly difficult situation. But I learnt a new word today, so thank you!

Comment: @simonatrcl Wow, that makes sence! Now, I can understand what the speaker wanted to say. Thank you!

Comment: The first thing I thougt of was the Phillip Glass Opera.  I see it was based on this concept. https://www.eno.org/operas/satyagraha/

Comment: @Karlomanio Thank you for commenting! I will check on it!

Comment: @simon at rcl: It's Gandhi' not Ghandi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when you have a sentence of the form

> This isn't just *A*, it's *N* *A*.

(where *A* is an adjective and *N* is a noun) it means that *N* is something that's known to be very *A*. This is a way of emphasizing how extreme something is, although it's usually used hyperbolically. An example would be:

> This isn't just cold, it's Antarctica cold.

This can even be used if the senses of the adjective are not the same. For instance, we can describe a person as being cold if they're not affectionate, so you could say:

> Joe is not just cold, he's Antarctica cold.

Joe's demeanor is being compared to Antarctica's temperature.

So in your example, "grey" and "black and white" appear to be used to describe how clear-cut some situation or decision is, and satyagraha is then being invoked by the first speaker as some well-known grey thing, to emphasize his point.